# Add additional value with row header on Googleform submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to add an extra value in the response sheet when a google form is submitted.

I wrote a code but can not get it to work.

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{var form = FormApp.openById('11xxxxxxxxxxxxxxdk');
var items = form.getItems();

 if (items[4] == "D" && items[6] =="Agree")
 {items[9]="TP"}
 else if(items[4] == "D" && items[6] =="Disagree")
 {items[9]="FP"}
 else if(items[4] == "A" && items[6] =="Disagree")
 {items[9]="FN"}
 else if(items[4] == "A" && items[6] =="Agree")
 {items[9]="TN"}
 else{}
e.range.offset(0, 11).setValue(items[9]);
}
```

where is the mistake in this code? Do I have to call spreadsheetApp as well to set the Value of the item.

I realize that the I am using a pre-filled form which has a different ID and not matching the original Form.
How Do I counter this issue.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but can not get it to work.` and your goal? Unfortunately, from your script and question, I couldn't understand about your goal. Because each element of `form.getItems()` is the item object, and it is not the string. And also, I cannot understand about `I realize that the I am using a pre-filled form which has a different ID and not matching the original Form.`. Also I would like to ask you about this.

Comment: I have a Pre-filled google form [link] (https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308781?hl=en). which has certain values pre-filled and some are filled by users. when user submit a form I want to add an extra item at the end of the column of my response sheet(Googlesheet).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation and goal from your replying.

Comment: what about pre-filling your form programmatically using [```createResponse```](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse)? In that way you can pre-fill your original form and the ```onFormSubmit``` will work normally. That workaround would work for you?